# IIS/ASP.NET MVC: Dynamic IP Address Restrictions on specific folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

Because of how it works, this would be trivial to do using WebForms, but I can't see a logical way to do it using MVC.
I've a part of my application (the public API) that I'd like to apply specific Dynamic IP Restrictions on it (so I need to have a Web.config file that applies only to some part of the app).
In WebForms, I'd simply create a folder and put a Web.config file in it with the associated restrictions.
Is there a way to do this with MVC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Location elements can still be used in MVC to apply configuration (like IP restrictions) to certain parts of your MVC app:

```
<location path="secret/api">
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
        <clear/>
        <add ipAddress="127.0.0.1"/>
      </ipSecurity>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Comment: I think I can also do what I want using Areas, I'll check on this also.